# Как проверить, защищен ли сайт от парсинга?

Tags: php, парсер, curl, безопасность, simple-html-dom

Есть много сайтов с большим объемом информации, которую надо парсить. Но как-то не хочется отдать свой ip в бан-базу cloudflare или самого сайта. Есть ли какие-то способы узнать, стоит ли защита, надо ли ограничивать запросы и т.д.

Спасибо.

*Пишу парсер на php curl

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под защитой от парсинга? Я думаю сайт зищитить можно только скрыть от других или открыть определенному кругу лиц, но какой от этого смысл?

Comment: @And я имею ввиду защиту cloudflare и подобную, которая банит ip из-за большого количества запросов.

Comment: Спросить у админа сайта.

Comment: не делать большое количество запросов, сделать имитацию, что сидит человек.

Comment: @andreymal лол... тогда можно напрямую попросить в него базу данных)

Comment: @And это если уже знаю, что есть защита. Но увеличивать время парсинга в несколько десятков раз в случае если нет защиты - не вариант. Надо наперед знать, чтобы сэкономить на сайтах без защиты

Comment: На нормальных сайтах везде стоят ограничения и как минимум `iptable` и если ограничения превышают хоть на 1, `банипа` накрывает.

Comment: @And я понимаю, но вопрос не в этом - есть ли возможность проверить?

Comment: Как вы проверите, вам же сказали, спросите тогда у админа, на что вы ответили. может базу попросить? Ну так, а как вы, проверите то, что стоит у них на сервере, странный вы какой-то.

Comment: @And возможно есть какой-то сервис, который делает запросы и проверяет это. Я же не знаю, поэтому и тут спрашиваю

Comment: Запускаете локально tor. Добавляете в curl его адрес как socks-proxy. Делаете тестовый прогон. Делаете выводы

Comment: Правда на многих сайтах тор превентивно забанен. Но можно и погуглить фри хттп-прокси